# Making a health bar dissapearing while clicking the attack button JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I want to make a visualisation of a health bar slowly dissapearing after clicking the attack button. Unfortunately I don't know how to convert `damage` as a percentage of the length of the `healthBar` to reduce its length. I would like its length to be reduced until it disappears completely.

Partially I understand that you would need to get `offsetWidth` etc but i dont know how to combine that with the `damage` variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = 'en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset = 'utf-8'>
            <title>HP</title>
    
    
            <style>
                .healthBar {
                    position: fixed;
                    width: 500px;
                    height: 20px;
                    background-color: red;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translateX(-50%);
                }
                .attack {
                    position: fixed;
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 20px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            </style>
    
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="healthBar"></div>
    
            <button class="attack">
                ATTACK
            </button>
    
            
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            
            const attack = document.querySelector('.attack');
            const healthBar = document.querySelector('.healthBar');
    
            let damage = 100;
            let HP = 200;
    
            attack.addEventListener('click', function(){
                if (HP > 0) {
                    HP = HP - damage;
                    if (HP <= 0) {
                        console.log('DEAD');
                        alert('DEAD');
                    }
                }
            })
    
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the percentage of something, you divide the current value by the total value. In this case, if I had 100 health and took 20 damage, 20/100 is 0.2 or 20%. 100% is always represented as the number 1, so you can reliably take this value and multiply it by 100 to get a percentage that's more friendly to the human eye.

I went ahead and tried myself to get this to work and I eventually did, so let me explain how I got my solution.

First, let's come up with a formula. Since you can use percentages to specify the width of an HTML element, let's just figure out how to get the percentage of remaining health. As I said before, current / total gives you the percentage, so all we need to do is get this value and multiply it by 100 in order for it to be a proper percent. The formula would look something like `(HP / totalHP) * 100`. Easy enough.

Now that we have a percent, we need to create a parent element for the health bar to represent the max health. For this, I will split your bar into 2 different elements with the classes `healthContainer`, and `healthBar`. `healthContainer` will be the parent element representing the max health, and `healthBar` will be the actual colored bar that gradually decreases. I will also add a border to `healthContainer` so you can see the difference.

Finally, we just need to keep track of the max health. I will just create a second variable called `maxHP` and set `HP` to it initially. This way, we can use the formula above to get what percentage the current HP is of the max HP and plug it into the `healthBar` element as the width. Here is the completed code:

```js
let attack = document.querySelector('.attack');
let healthBar = document.querySelector('.healthBar');

let damage = 100;
let maxHP = 200;
let HP = maxHP;

attack.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (HP > 0) {
    HP = HP - damage;
    healthBar.style.width = ((HP / maxHP) * 100) + '%';
    if (HP <= 0) {
      console.log('DEAD');
      alert('DEAD');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.healthContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.healthBar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.attack {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="healthContainer">
  <div class="healthBar"></div>
</div>

<button class="attack">
ATTACK
</button>
```